# Protractor modal dialog returns multiple results for ng-repeater

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, protractor

I am trying to click on an element located within a repeater.  The problem is that is a modal dialog and returns multiple elements for the repeater.  When you go to a page in our application, each page within that is then a modal dialog.  So when you navigate to a page, the prior page is actually still there ‘under’ the page you’re seeing.  This was done to support being able to navigate back to exactly where you were (no reload) after hitting a back button.  Hitting the back button just closes the current modal and reveals the content that was hidden beneath that modal.

Here is the repeater I am using:

```
this.searchResults      = element.all(by.repeater('provider in providers'));
```

This is what is returned (I did a search in the console for the class just so I could see what was being returned):
[image]

How can I get one of the results returned from the repeater to click on the element within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.searchResults` would contain an [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) (basically, an array of elements), which you can operate with in multiple ways. For instance, to get a specific element:

```
this.searchResults.get(2);
this.searchResults.first();
this.searchResults.last();
```

Then, you can *chain* it with `element` or `all` to search inside the repeater row:

```
this.searchResults.get(2).element(by.css(".provider-list-info-link"));
```

There are also functional programming "tools" available like [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map), [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) functions.

Additionally, you can get to repeater rows and columns via [`row()` and `column()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater).

Comment: The only change I had to make was to use 0 or 1 instead of 2 but otherwise this helped, thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity -- one of my issues was that I was trying to do this.searchResults.then(function(results).....    and then working off of results.  Because I thought that the repeater returned a promise.  How come it works without needing to use .then here?

Comment: @rfodge yeah, this is what protractor handles internally. Chaining is something that was separately implemented ([changeset](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/cc4f7b55e1fe46fcef1b8c3ca39d702a32ee6d82)).